# unable to refresh data fields in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reporting, ssrs-2008-r2

i am trying to update a report. i have stored procedure in my database for getting the fields for data set.i updated the stored procedure for new data fields, and the stored procedure is working properly. but when i try to refresh the fields in the data set it shows the error "Could not update a list of fields for the query. Verify that you can connect to the data source and the query syntax is correct."

i am using a shared data source. and connection to the data source is working. it was worked yesterday but now i am not able to refresh data fields.

please help me

thanks in advance

Comment: try this. http://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2012/2/6/workaround-for-could-not-update-a-list-of-fields-for-the-que.html

Comment: i did the same but it is not working @Snowlockk

Comment: Can you expand to show details of the error, it usually gives more information.

Comment: Have you removed any fields from your stored procedure?

Comment: Or are there any duplicate fields?

Comment: no i added a new field in my stored procedure @RaviMatani

Comment: "The shared data source 'rptConn' does not exist or you do not have sufficient permissions. For more information, contact your report server administrator." this is the error showing @AlanSchofield

Comment: No duplicate fields @Snowlockk

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem.

I login to my system using different account. That's why my access credentials are different.i solved this problem by changing my account.

their is one more chance to occur this problem. that is when our credentials to the data source is not correct at that time also we got the same error.